# How can I replace the variables by floats in the equations using python

Tags: python

I am writing a code to calculate the propagation of error for an instrumentation course. the code asks you to input the equation, the variables that contain errors, their values and uncertainties. it then derives the equation with respect to the inputted variables and stores it in a list. I am trying to replace the variables of the derived equations by their values, multiply this whole operation by the uncertainty and repeat the process for each index in the list. afterwards i want to do the sum of the square root of all the indices of this list to get the value of the propagation of error.
I am stuck at replacing the value of the variables in the derived equations and need help. I tried re.sub()  and .replace() however they didnt work since im trying to replace them by a float. I am going to post the code and output. Thank you for your help.

Code:

```py
from sympy import diff, Symbol
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
print('Propagation of error: ')
exp=str(input('Enter the expression to find the propagation of error: '))
var=list(map(str,input('Enter the variables containing uncertainty seperated by spaces: ').split())) 
val=list(map(float,input('Enter the values of the variables in the same order seperated by spaces: ').split()))
x=list(map(float,input('Enter the values of the uncertainty of each variable in the same order seperated by spaces: ').split())) 
L=[]
for i in range(len(var)):  
    symb={var[i]:Symbol(var[i],real=True)}
    func=parse_expr(exp,symb)
    L.append(diff(func,symb[var[i]]))
print(L)
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues with OP Code**

With string expression is: `3*E**2+5*K*E**3`

- You are parsing string expression only using a single symbol at a time i.e. K, E
- The first loop uses the symbol K, but not E.  So E is interpreted as exp().
- The partial with respect to K then becomes 5*exp(3)

**Calculation of Propagation Error**

[Source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Quantifying_Nature/Significant_Digits/Propagation_of_Error)

For a function of three variables in a, b, c i.e.:

[image]

The square of propagation error is:

[image]

Here, we want to apply this to a function of two variables: K, E.

**Code**

```
from sympy import diff, Symbol
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

# Setup
print('Propagation of error: ')
exp = input('Enter the expression to find the propagation of error: ')
var = input('Enter the variables containing uncertainty seperated by spaces: ').split()
values = [float(v) for v in input('Enter the values of the variables in the same order seperated by spaces: ').split()]
undertainties = [float(v) for v in input('Enter the values of the uncertainty of each variable in the same order seperated by spaces: ').split()]

# Create Symbol Table for variables 
#   (i.e. dictionary of variable names mapped to sympy symbols)
symb = {x:Symbol(x, real = True) for x in var}  

# Table for values of symbols (i.e. dictionary of symbols mapped to values)
val_table = {symb[x]:v for x, v in zip(var, values)}

# Symbolic expression using symbol table
func = parse_expr(exp, symb)  

# List of partial derivatives
derivatives = [diff(func, symb[x]) for x in var]

# Error is sum of partials squared times undertainty squared
# Use val_table for local values for symbols
error = sum((u**2)*d.evalf(subs=val_table)**2 for u, d in zip(undertainties, derivatives))
print(f'Propgation error is: {error**0.5}')  # Square root of sum of squares
```

**Output**

```
Propagation of error: 
Enter the expression to find the propagation of error: 3*E**2+5*K*E**3
Enter the variables containing uncertainty separated by spaces: K E
Enter the values of the variables in the same order separated by spaces: 10 15
Enter the values of the uncertainty of each variable in the same order separated by spaces: 0.1 0.15
Propagation error is: 5349.15247959899
```